# How should I go about adding actionability to common interface elements (like commits)?

Tags: magit

<sup>I was on the fence about raising this on GitHub, but it's not necessarily a feature request and it certainly isn't a bug report.</sup>

I'd like to add some actionability to every reference to commits within Magit.  For instance, I'd like to add a 'browse this commit on GitHub' feature to Magithub, but I don't want to track down all the places commits are displayed to a user – I'd like to just say 'commit references should have this additional behavior' and have that *just work*.

Soon, I'll want to do something similar for branches, and I can easily see this list growing.  A one-off solution for commits clearly won't scale well.

Is this possible already in Magit?  If not, how should an implementation approach this?  My guess is that the text should use a local keymap that can be modified by consumers.  (If the latter, I will definitely add this as a feature request on the tracker and link the discussions together.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each section has a type and for some section types, including the ones you have mentioned, a type-specific keymap exists named `magit-TYPE-section-map`. Also look at the various `magit-*-at-point` functions in `magit-git.el` and how they are used in hairy cases elsewhere.

To get information about the section at point use `M-x magit-describe-section`. The first symbol inside the printed vector is the section type.

A section (currently) can only have one type, which can complicate matters. For example all children of a log have type `commit`, even those that a tag and/or branch point at.

So if you want a command to be available whenever there is a branch at point, then you would have to bind it not only in `magit-branch-section-map` but also `magit-commit-section-map`. And then you would have to dispatch again inside the command itself. The functions I have mention help here, but you should also read [Matching Sections](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Matching-Sections.html).

Comment: @SeanAllred Does that answer your question?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response; oddly, I didn't get a notification for this.